# unexpected return value, after setjmp

Tags: linux, signals

I tried to get the return value in the signal handler function, using the longjmp(), but the program return which is not what I expected. Can someone help me? The code is as follows:

```
void SignalHandler(int sig)
{
    longjmp(frameInfo, -2);
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    signal(SIGSEGV, SignalHandler);
    if(setjmp(frameInfo) == 0) {
        void* ptr = NULL;
        int a = *((int *)ptr);
        printf("%d\n", a);
        return -1;
    } else {
        printf("in \n"); // printf can work
        exit(-2); // or return -2;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

I don't know what happened after the printf.

update:

By check assemble code, I see the expected return value.

```
mov    $0xfffffffe,%eax
```

Compile code and generate a.out, use python or shell check return, ret = 254:

```
// python
cmd = ./a.out
a = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell = True)
ret = a.wait()

// shell
./a.out
echo $?
```

My guess is that after the program returned, the operating system did something special. The question is how do I get the real return value?

Comment: 0xfe == 254 == -2 for 1-byte value

Comment: use signal 6, return value is -11. I don't think it's a simple overflow problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and also show us what output and exit value you got.  Please further provide the output and exit value you expected and why.

Comment: Almost there.  Please include headers and defines, if any, needed for compilation.  Please _show the output of your tests_ (e.g., of `echo $?`) and also tell us what you expected to see instead.

Comment: @pilcrow : Problem closed, about "use signal 6, return value is -11", I triggered the signal in the wrong way. stark is right. When a positive integer is returned, python and echo $? work properly.